# Assigning UIImageView an image issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that I attached to a scroll view, and whenever the scroll view scrolled I want to set an image to this UIImageView (I use different UIImageView because whenever the scroll view contentOffset property get to a certain point I want to change the Image to some other image).

So i added this three properties to my view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *vMarkIcn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *greenVmarkIcn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *currentScrollImage;
```

in my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
   //this is the initial image i want to be
    self.currentScrollImage.image = self.vMarkIcn.image;
}
```

my `scrollViewDidScroll` :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (self.myScrollView.contentOffset.y <= -73) {

        self.currentScrollImage.image = self.greenVmarkIcn.image;
    }
    NSLog(@"%f", self.myScrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

and lastly in my `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` I change it back to the vMarkIcn:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    self.currentScrollImage.image = self.vMarkIcn.image;
}
```

iv set currentScrollImage to be scale to fill, but the size of the vMarkIcn gets weird...what am I doing wrong here? :/

it's like stretched or something...

images sizes:

```
currentScrollImage = 50x50
vMarkIcn = 28x20
greenVmarkIcn = 50x50
```

but I want the currentScrollImage to scale to the sizes of the other images

thanksss

Comment: Some screenshots would help, and to know the sizes of all of the images

Comment: @Wain i added the sizes bro

Comment: the problem is with the the vMarkIcn obviously because of the size differences, but I want the  currentScrollImage to scale to the vMarkIcn size..

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not completely clear, especially since it's not clear if the sizes are those of images or image views, but it sounds that you want `UIViewContentModeCenter` rather than `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. This would not resize or stretch the images, but rather just keep their original sizes and center them inside the image views.

Comment: Well, then your image assets are larger than the sizes that you posted. It's generally not good practice to scale images down by putting them into a smaller image view (performance, blurry images due to resizing), but if you want to go that route, you'd need to adjust the size of your `currentScrollImage` to the desired size every time you set a new image.

Comment: and how can I change currentScrollImage to the vMarkIcn size for instance?

Comment: Since your images are larger than you want them displayed, you don't want to use the size of the *image*, but rather the size of your image view. Something like `currentScrollImage.bounds = vMarkIcn.bounds` should do the trick. But honestly, the whole approach seems a bit dirty (but I must admit that I didn't take very much time to try to understand it).

Comment: i tried to set the bounds like you said, its not working unfortunately. i'm sure as you said that my code to accomplish this  task is probably clumsy, but I dont know another way...i'm trying to perform something simple, I have a label and i added to this label an image that is set to a certain offset that when i scroll the label (that sits in a scroll view) the image is poping, but I want to change that image according to some specific offset

Comment: Ok, I have the impression you only need one image view (the one that is scrolled), not three. Just set the desired image directly (`currentScrollImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]`). Ideally I would resize the image assets to not be larger than you want them to be displayed, and also to be the same size in the first place (that is, for example, add some padding around your smaller image). But I can't do your work inside the SO comments and especially not if I don't have all the code, so good luck. :)